# Как бегущую строку сделать более плавной и гладкой?

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется код который запускает label и он движется ровно от середины до края.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (this.label.Left <= -this.label.Width)
  {
     this.label.Left = this.panel.Width;
  }
  else
  {
     this.label.Left -= 5;
  }
}
```

1 - Как сделать более плавный бег?

2 - Как сделать от начала края формы и до конца формы и по новой?

[**Обновлено**]

Двойная буферизация в форме включена.

Таймер делаю так:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 190;
timer.Tick += this.timer1_Tick;
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Очевидно, Вы можете уменьшить интервал срабатывания таймера и понизить "шаг" сдвига

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Но анимация в любом случае дёргается, я пробовал от самого меньшего к самому больше ставить не помогло, есть ли какие-нибудь средства сделать плавное движения? Или это нужно писать анимацию высчитывать координаты и.т.п?

Comment: Даже при сдвиге в один пиксель за тик дергается? У Вас двойная буферизация включена?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Конечно включена буферизация изначально, даже при сдвиге в один пиксель идёт дёрганье.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста, код включения двойной буферизации. И дайте данные по таймеру (по его интервалам)